# Running Termux commands from Bixby capsule?

Tags: termux, bixby

I ran into a wall with the functionality of Routines and Routines+ - specifically the fact that touch macros only work when the screen is unlocked (which makes sense but still annoying).

I thought that was it and I was out of luck, but then found reference to capsules, and it seems Samsung is encouraging developers to add functionality to Bixby, which is nice. I don't know how to directly add something to Bixby Routines, so please tell me if this path isn't worth pursuing, however I do know that voice and custom commands can be run from Routines.

My end goal is to be able to run Termux commands from Bixby Routines, which I'm hoping is possible based upon this: https://github.com/termux/termux-app/wiki/RUN_COMMAND-Intent. I've never done anything with Bixby development wise, so I'm wondering if this is something that can be done from a capsule?